# Java- get user home on user machine not on server

Tags: java, applet

I came across `System.getProperty("user.home")` and `System.getProperty("user.dir")` in java, but those are returning paths from the **server**.
I have an applet and want to create a folder based on the user directory on the **client**, is there any way to get that information?

Comment: Seems insecure.  Applets can't know about those details.  Who still uses applets?  Did we go back to 1995 all of a sudden?

Comment: @duffymo....Thanks for your help!

Comment: if these System properties return the server's path values - you probably **run** them on the server. I suppose your app is client/server somehow?

Comment: @Jan yes my app is client/server; from jsp page System properties are return server's values

Comment: JSP always run in server, and can't access client/browser variables

Comment: were you able to resolve your issues?

Comment: yes look at my solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by placing the following code inside jar file and sign the jar

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.PrivilegedAction;

public class UserHomeApplet
  extends Applet
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;




  public String getUserHome()
  {

     AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction()
      {
        public Object run()
        {
          return System.getProperty("user.home");
        }
      }).toString();
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can check which System properties are available in your applet:

- Enable Java Console in your Java Settings (show console)

[image: javaconsole]

- Run your applet. Java-Console should show up.
- Press "s" to show your system properties and check for "user.home" value

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, it shows the right value but when i print it in jsp file it reads server value, any suggestion on how to get it?

Comment: JSP runs on server. You might get away with sending local user als parameter to jsp